# What term do i need to add to this function?

Tags: calculus

What kind of term do I need to add to this function $$l=3\operatorname{csch}(t)\operatorname{sech}^3(t) (-2 + 3 \tanh(t))$$

So it takes a constant (probably very small) value for $t\gg1$.

Motivation:

Its a function I calculated for the cosmological constant plugging in a specific einstein tensorfield into the vacuum field equations. There is an additional scaling factor which is the initial scalar curvature of a $3$ dimensional Einstein manifold. So basicly the function should stay constant after inflation but it decreases very rapidly. It should stay at $10^{-122}$.

Comment: Add $3csch(t) sech^3(t) (2 - 3 tanh(t))$ and it takes a (very small) constantfor $t\gg 1$ ...

Comment: MathJax hint:  If you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing.  If the function is not common enough, use \operatorname{csch}(t) to get $ \operatorname{csch}(t)$

Comment: How constant do you want?  For large $t$ both sech and csch go to zero as $e^{-t}$, while tanh goes to $1$, so the whole expression goes to zero about as $e^{-4t}$

Comment: Thanks alot. Its a function I calculated for the cosmological constant plugging in a specific einstein tensorfield into the vacuum field equations. There is an additional scaling factor which is the initial scalar curvature of a 3 dimensional einstein manifold. So basicly the function should stay constant after inflation but it decreases very rapidly. It should stay at 10^-122

Comment: Use `$t\gg 1$` for the output $t\gg 1$.